# My querySelectorALL returns an empty node list

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch-api

I fetched some data from a JSON file I served, this data is used to generate some divs on my website.
In each divs an additionally button will be generated, now I'm trying to select the buttons with `querySelectorall` but I get an empty nodelist.
When I save the data directly in the js file without serving it as a JSON file and map through it, this error does not occur.

```js
async function getEmployees() {
    let response = await
    fetch("  http://localhost:3000/img")
    let data = await response.json()
    return data;
}

getEmployees().then((data) => gallery((data)))

function gallery(data) {
    data.map(e => {
        const {
            images,
            quote
        } = e;
        imagescontainer.innerHTML += `<div class="image-box">
      // this is the button im trying to access

    <a class="btn play-music-btn image-btn" id="playbtn">Play Songs</a>
            <div class="img">
                <img src="${images}" alt="">
            </div>
            <h3 class= "image-text">${quote}</h3>
      </div>`
    })
}

let imageBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.image-btn');
console.log(imgeBtn);
```

The last line of code returns an empty node list.

I have heard I can use promises to solve the problem, but I have not been able to work my way around it.

Comment: The code formatting is pretty inconsistent, but currently it suggests that you're trying to select the elements before they exist, rather than after appending them to the DOM.

Comment: You've called `querySelectorAll` before the callback you pass to `then` has run.